# .movpkg conversion to normal format

Tags: video, appletv, quicktime

I've bought a few movies on AppleTV and after downloading them I wanted to copy them onto an USB stick as an example so I can watch them on other devices easily. The problem here is though, that like its common for Apple it's not made to be used with anything other than Apple.

So, the movie I downloaded is an .movpkg file. I looked on the web on how I can convert it, I have found a GitHub page which has a python script capable of converting the .movpkg to .ts files(https://github.com/opa334/SafariPlus/blob/master/movpkgmerge.py). I also get an output after having to modify it so the script doesn't look for an .m3u8 with its folder name but rather just the .m3u8 file(the modified script is at the bottom).

The problem then is that ffmpeg says this:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13f604c40] could not find corresponding track id 0
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13f604c40] trun track id unknown, no tfhd was found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13f604c40] error reading header
```

So something can't be right, I hope that someone can help figure this out!

Thank you in advance!

Modified script:

```
import sys
import os
import re
import string
import sys

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def printUsage():
    print('Usage: movpkgmerge.py (-r) <target directory>')
    print('-r: Recursively convert all .movpkg folders inside the target directory.')
    print('If not using -r, target directory should be the movpkg to convert')

def isMp4(trackPath):  # hello, this is the guy who made the request on stack exchange and this is the function chat gpt changed to get an output
    files = os.listdir(trackPath)
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.m3u8'):
            filePath = os.path.join(trackPath, file)
            trackInfoFile = open(filePath, "r")
            lines = trackInfoFile.readlines()
            trackInfoFile.close()
            for line in lines:
                if '#EXT-X-MAP:URI=' in line:
                    return 1
            return 0
    return 0


def atoi(text):
    return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text

def natural_keys(text):
    return [ atoi(c) for c in re.split(r'(\d+)', text) ]
    
def mergeMovPkg(pathToMovPkg):
    trackDirectories = [f for f in listdir(pathToMovPkg) if f != 'Data' and f != 'boot.xml' and f != 'root.xml']

    for trackDirectory in trackDirectories:
        trackDirectoryPath = join(pathToMovPkg,trackDirectory)
        trackIsMp4 = isMp4(trackDirectoryPath)
        trackNum = trackDirectory.split('-')[0]
        
        extension = 'ts'
        # if trackIsMp4:
        #     extension = 'mp4'             # its me again, by commenting this out i get rid of the .mp4 output files which seemed useless because ffmpeg needs .ts

        if len(trackDirectories) > 1:
            exportFilePath = os.path.splitext(pathToMovPkg)[0] + '_track' + trackNum + '.' + extension
        else:
            exportFilePath = os.path.splitext(pathToMovPkg)[0] + '.' + extension
        
        if os.path.exists(exportFilePath):
            print("%s already exists, skipping" % os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(exportFilePath)))
            continue
        exportFile = open(exportFilePath,'ab+')
        
        trackFragments = [f for f in listdir(trackDirectoryPath) if str.endswith(f, '.frag') or str.endswith(f, '.initfrag')]
        trackFragments.sort(key=natural_keys)
        for fragmentFileName in trackFragments:
            fragmentFile = open(join(trackDirectoryPath, fragmentFileName), 'rb')
            exportFile.write(fragmentFile.read())
            fragmentFile.close()
        exportFile.close()
        print('Merged track %s of %s to %s' %(trackDirectory, os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(pathToMovPkg)), os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(exportFilePath))))

recursive = 0
for arg in sys.argv:
    if '-r' in arg:
        recursive = 1

if len(sys.argv) < 2 or len(sys.argv) > 2 + recursive:
    printUsage()
    sys.exit(0)
    
specifiedPath = sys.argv[-1]
if not os.path.exists(specifiedPath):
    print('Error: No directory at path %s' % specifiedPath)
    sys.exit(1)

if recursive:
    movPkgNames = [f for f in listdir(specifiedPath) if str.endswith(f, '.movpkg')]
    for movPkgName in movPkgNames:
        movPkgPath = join(specifiedPath, movPkgName)
        mergeMovPkg(movPkgPath)
else:
    mergeMovPkg(specifiedPath)
```